# How to find best match with sklearn pipeline in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've got a Pipeline setup using a TfidfVectorizer and TruncatedSVD. I train the models with sklearn and calculate the distance between two vectors using the cosine similarity. Here's my code:

```
def create_scikit_corpus(leaf_names=None):

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
        tokenizer=Tokenizer(),
        stop_words='english',
        use_idf=True,
        smooth_idf=True
    )

    svd_model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=300,
                             algorithm='randomized',
                             n_iterations=10,
                             random_state=42)
    svd_transformer = Pipeline([('tfidf', vectorizer),
                                ('svd', svd_model)])

    svd_matrix = svd_transformer.fit_transform(leaf_names)

    logging.info("Models created")

    test = "This is a test search query."
    query_vector = svd_transformer.transform(test)
    distance_matrix = pairwise_distances(query_vector, svd_matrix, metric='cosine')


    return svd_transformer, svd_matrix
```

The thing is that I'm not sure what to do once I have the distance_matrix variable. I guess I'm kinda confused on exactly what that is.

I'm trying to find which document matches best with my query. Thanks for a push in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the distance_matrix computed, you can find the closest singular vector according to the cosine similarity... And that might be the reason you are confused: what does this singular vector represent?

The problem is that this answer is not straightforward, the singular vector is usually not a document in your corpus.

If what you want is the **best match** as in "the document from your corpus that is the most similar to this one", there is something simpler to do: pick the closest document according to cosine similarity. You do not need SVD for this approach.